# Modify tags for multiple photos

Tags: shotwell

I need to modify tags in multiple photos. It seems I have to do it manually one by one. I tried selecting more than one, but then the modify tag options doesn't work. Is there a way around this? Am I doing something wrong?
ton

Comment: I have the same "problem". This would really be a nice new feature to shotwell. Somehow I think that this feature was once implemented?!? But I could be wrong here...

Answer (score 3):

> To remove a tag from one or more photos, first select that tag in the
>   sidebar, then select the photos you would like to remove, and choose
>   Tags ▸ Remove Tag "[name]" from Photos or right-click on the photos an
>   select Remove Tag "[name]" from Photos.

Source: http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/tag.html

Comment: Recent versions of shotwell seem to no longer support this?

Comment: Relevant bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/-/issues/52

Answer (score 0):

Install **ExifTool**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

View Tags:

```
$ exiftool input.jpg
```

Modify tags for multiple images:

```
$ exiftool -artist="Bon Jovu" -copyright="2013 Bon Jovi" a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg
```

For all images in a folder:

```
$ for i in *; \
  do exiftool -artist="Bon Jovu" -copyright="2013 Bon Jovi" $i; \
  done;
```

Comment: After installing libimage-exiftool-perl, I tried the same for exiftool input.jpg, even though there was no command I usually use, like apt-get. Rereading my question I noticed I didn't add it was for shotwell. Does that make a differnce for your answer? And how do i proceed after the firt install?

Comment: If your images are `in /home/user/Pictures`,after installing do  `$ cd /home/user/Pictures`, then run the above commands.

Comment: I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so I did what you suggested, but this command was not recognised. As it is not a very big thing, I am merely surprised you cannot undo tags for more than one picture, I might wait untill I meet a person with Ubuntu. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @TonBaars what do you mean command not recognized? Add the output of what you get in the question.